# Differentiability of a topological map on the boundary

Tags: derivatives

Let $(\mathfrak{T},\mathcal{O})$ be a topological space, where $\mathfrak{T}=[0,1]$ is a closed interval, and $\mathcal{O}$ is the standard topology on $\mathfrak{T}$.

Let $f:(\mathfrak{T},\mathcal{O})\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{R})$ be a topological map given by $f(t)=5t^2-3t+4$. Then, $f'(t)=10t-3$. My question is... is $f$ differentiable on $\partial\mathfrak{T}:=\{0,1\}$?

Being $[0,1]\in\mathcal{O}$ an open set, the answer should be yes. But I am not quite sure.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. This question seems weirdly phrased. For instance, what is the reason for including the first paragraph? Why not just say "let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(t)=5t^2-3t+4$. And what do you mean by "topological map"?. Your function is a polynomial, so it's everywhere differentiable and thus has lateral derivatives on the boundary. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Hi Reveillark, By topological map I mean a relation between two topological spaces. This relation is prescribed by $f$ which is given by $f(t)=5t^2-3t+4$. I learnt from high school that one cannot differentiate a function on the boundary of a closed interval. However, my understanding is that if the domain of the function has been equipped with a topology, then one can write $f'(0)=-3$ without stressing the fact that by $f'(0)$ one means $f'(0^+)$.

Comment: I think the concept you are looking for is "manifolds with boundary", this might help: http://math.ucr.edu/~res/math260s10/manwithbdy.pdf

Comment: Thanks Qidi, I will check it out.